What types to specify for Text.Json source generator?
I'm using the System.Text.Json source generator but could not find information on what types I need to specify for the JsonSerializerContext.
If I have these dto:s
public class OrderDto {
    ...
    public List<OrderLineDto> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineDto {
    ...
}

used in various places like
JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<OrderDto>>(...);
JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<OrderDto>(...);
JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<OrderLineDto>>(...);
JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<OrderLineDto>(...);

Is it enough to just have the [JsonSerializable(typeof(OrderDto))] attribute or do I need to have one attribute for each "root" used in DeserializeAsync?
Edit: Sorry I missed  the part about collection in the documentation

To specify source generation for a collection, use [JsonSerializable] with the collection type.

But the documentation just says

The types of WeatherForecast members don't need to be explicitly specified with [JsonSerializable] attributes.

Does that mean DeserializeAsync<List<OrderLineDto>> works without [JsonSerializable(typeof(List<OrderLineDto>))] because the type already exists as a member of OrderDto?
A bit of a background.
I have a library with autogenerated types used in an API. The complete list of all types used results in ~250 attributes  which expands to ~1650 "source generated files" which sometimes get slow (and triples the size of the library). Since almost all types are listed twice (i.e. Dto and List<Dto>) and a lot of them are also members of other types I wondered if I could optimize it.

It seems answers start to RTFM you. I assume you are well aware of that documentation and still have doubts? Can you elaborate why that is?

@Fildor, see edit. But in general the documentation doesn't say if there is a one to one relationship between the JsonSerializableAttribute and DeserializeAsync method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation#deserialization-examples
